# Uploading an XLSX converting and replacing a current spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Just a general question, I would like to create a user upload form that would convert an .xlsx to the corresponding Google Sheets version and then replace a currently existing sheet on my drive. The main question and aspect that I'm not sure is achievable is replacing a current google sheet. Is a project like this even achievable in a reasonable manner? The reason I want to replace it is because the KeyID for that sheet is used in a couple other app scripts for a website. Thanks for the suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. About being "reasonable", well... I think it is, it's not a single line script, but this is not the most simple task either.

But from what I understood from your use-case (other app script for a website), I think it's better if you enhance your other scripts to either look for the newest sheet on a given folder or fetch the ID from somewhere that you can update from the "form upload" script. Also, by doing this, you'll avoid getting inconsistent data in the middle of an update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll probably just update the other scripts. I liked the idea of fetching the ID so I'll give that a shot. I'll probably just record the uploaded ID in a spreadsheet and have the other scripts reference that sheet.